# Reduce latency of Bot Connector

Tags: bots, botframework, botconnector

I figured out that there's always latency of about two to three seconds when sending messages through the Bot Connector of Microsoft's Bot Framework independent of which channel type I'm using.

This means if I call the POST .../messages API method of my Bot directly (so not going through the Bot Connector) I get an answer within several dozens ms. However, if messages are routed through bot connector (e.g. when I use Direct Line communication or Telegram or any other supported channel) it always takes about two to three seconds until I get an answer.

For a possible user this would not be a good user experience so that I'm wondering whether either I'm doing someting wrong (e.g. Bot Connector settings) or whether this is a general problem and will be improved at a later pont of time.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue.  The BotFramework is still in Preview, so it has yet to be optimized.  Expect to see significant performance improvements in the near future.

Comment: Hi @Lars. I am using Direct Connect for a bot and am still seeing latency of 1.5-2.5 seconds for a POST to create a new message and receive a response. Is there any update on optimisation for Direct Connect?